# UrBackup Server Installation fails

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, software-installation

I am trying to install the UrBackup Server on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 9 (stretch) (fresh install).

I followed the steps described in the [installation notes](https://www.urbackup.org/debianserverinstall.html):

```
wget https://hndl.urbackup.org/Server/2.2.8/urbackup-server_2.2.8_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i urbackup-server_2.2.8_armhf.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

However, this resulted in the following error:

```
chown: missing operand after ‘urbackup:urbackup’
```

Here is the full trace:

```
Preparing to unpack urbackup-server_2.2.8_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking urbackup-server (2.2.8.0) ...
Setting up urbackup-server (2.2.8.0) ...
chown: missing operand after ‘urbackup:urbackup’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package urbackup-server (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 urbackup-server
```

How can I install UrBackup Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the UrBackup Server yourself. Follow these steps to **install from sources**, basically described in the [documentation](https://www.urbackup.org/server_source_install.html):

0. Install dependencies:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install libzstd-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libcrypto++-dev
   ```
1. Tidy up the faulty installation attempt to prevent further errors while using `apt-get`:

   ```
    sudo dpkg -r urbackup-server
   ```
2. Download the UrBackup Server source package

   ```
    wget https://hndl.urbackup.org/Server/2.4.11/urbackup-server-2.4.11.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract and navigate to the folder

   ```
    tar xf urbackup-server-2.4.11.tar.gz
    cd urbackup-server-2.4.11/
   ```
4. Configure

   ```
    ./configure
   ```
5. Make, do not run multiple threads (`make -j 4`), this might lead to errors, see below. This may take a while (20-30 minutes):

   ```
    make
   ```
6. Install

   ```
    sudo make install
   ```
7. [Add UrBackup to the system startup](https://www.urbackup.org/server_source_install.html)
8. [Auto-mount USB drive](https://gist.github.com/etes/aa76a6e9c80579872e5f)

---

Some sidenotes for these steps if **errors** occur:

- **`configure: error: Your system lacks of libcurl >= 7.20.0`**

  - run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` to install the missing library
  - run `./configure` again.
- **`Crypto++ not found. Please install (cryptopp-devel/libcrypto++-dev) or run configure with --enable-embedded-cryptopp.`**

  - run `sudo apt-get install libcrypto++-dev` to install the missing library
  - run `./configure` again.
- **`g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus) Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate. See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions. Makefile:4665: recipe for target 'urbackupserver/urbackupsrv-FileBackup.o' faile               d make[2]: *** [urbackupserver/urbackupsrv-FileBackup.o] Error 4 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... mv -f urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-ImageBackup.Tpo urbackupserver/.deps/urba               ckupsrv-ImageBackup.Po mv -f urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-FullFileBackup.Tpo urbackupserver/.deps/u               rbackupsrv-FullFileBackup.Po mv -f urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-IncrFileBackup.Tpo urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-IncrFileBackup.Po make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/urbackup-server-2.2.8' Makefile:6337: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/urbackup-server-2.2.8' Makefile:1338: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2`**

  - Run `make` instead of `make -j 4`
- **`g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus compilation terminated. make[2]: *** [Makefile:4968: urbackupserver/urbackupsrv-IncrFileBackup.o] Error 1 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... mv -f urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-FileMetadataDownloadThread.Tpo urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-FileMetadataDownloadThread.Po mv -f urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-FullFileBackup.Tpo urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-FullFileBackup.Po mv -f urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-restore_client.Tpo urbackupserver/.deps/urbackupsrv-restore_client.Po make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/urbackup-server-2.4.11' make[1]: *** [Makefile:5828: all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/urbackup-server-2.4.11' make: *** [Makefile:1219: all] Error 2`**

  - Run `make` instead of `make -j 4`

Comment: Note that configuration files such as `server_ident.key` are stored under `/usr/local/var/urbackup/`